# An argument type mismatch in crypto::hmac::Hmac::new

Tags: rust

I'm using https://github.com/DaGenix/rust-crypto and having some odd error:

```
extern crate crypto;
use crypto::sha2::{Sha256, Sha384, Sha512};
use crypto::hmac::Hmac;
use crypto::digest::Digest;
use crypto::mac::Mac;


enum MyType {
  Type1,
  Type2,
  Type3
}

//......

let mut hmac = Hmac::new(match myType {
   MyType::Type1 => Sha256::new(),
   MyType::Type2 => Sha384::new(),
   MyType::Type3 => Sha512::new()
  }, my_secret.to_string().as_bytes()
);
```

The error is:

```
error: match arms have incompatible types:
 expected `crypto::sha2::Sha256`,
    found `crypto::sha2::Sha384`
(expected struct `crypto::sha2::Sha256`,
    found struct `crypto::sha2::Sha384`) [E0308]
   let mut hmac = Hmac::new(match algorithm {
       MyType::Type1 => Sha256::new(),
       MyType::Type2 => Sha384::new(),
       MyType::Type3 => Sha512::new(),
       _ => panic!()
     }, secret.to_string().as_bytes()
 note: match arm with an incompatible type
       MyType::Type2 => Sha384::new(),
                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
 help: methods from traits can only be called if the trait is implemented and in scope; the following traits define a method `input`, perhaps you need to implement one of them:
 help: candidate #1: `crypto::cryptoutil::FixedBuffer`
 help: candidate #2: `crypto::digest::Digest`
 help: candidate #3: `crypto::mac::Mac`
 help: methods from traits can only be called if the trait is implemented and in scope; the following traits define a method `result`, perhaps you need to implement one of them:
 help: candidate #1: `crypto::digest::Digest`
 help: candidate #2: `crypto::mac::Mac`
```

Why is that? Doesn't `Sha256::new()` have the same type as `Sha384::new()` and `Sha512::new()`?

Answer (score 5):

> Doesn't `Sha256::new()` have the same type as `Sha384::new()` and `Sha512::new()`?

No.  They're *very clearly* different types if you look at the source code, nevermind the compiler *telling you* that they're different types.

More than that, you're also trying to create one of three different kinds of `Hmac` in a single expression, which is *also* impossible.  If you look at the definition in the source, you'll see

```
impl <D: Digest> Hmac<D> {
    // ...
    pub fn new(mut digest: D, key: &[u8]) -> Hmac<D> {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

That is, there's a different `Hmac` type for every possible `Digest` type.

You need to go through some kind of dynamic dispatch for this to work.  For example:

```
let (hmac_sha256, hmac_sha384, hmac_sha512);
let mac: &mut crypto::mac::Mac = match myType {
    MyType::Type1 => {
        hmac_sha256 = Hmac::new(Sha256::new(), my_secret.to_string().as_bytes();
        &mut hmac_sha256 as &mut crypto::mac::Mac
    },
    // ...
};
```

Or you could use `Box`es if references won't work.

Comment: **No. They're very clearly different types if you look at the source code, nevermind the compiler telling you that they're different types.** - they **all** implement the trait Digest and `Hmac::new()` accepts `Digest` as well. How can they be a different type?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp: That they implement a common trait is irrelevant: they are different types.  All builtin integers implement `Int`, but they are still different types.  The `Digest` trait is just a common interface for interacting with multiple, distinct types.

Comment: But `Hmac::new()` accepts `Digest` (**not** only the type which `Sha256` has). What does that mean? `Hmac::new()`  can accept any struct which implements it.

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp: No, it doesn't.  If you look at the [code where `Hmac::new` is defined](https://github.com/DaGenix/rust-crypto/blob/master/src/hmac.rs#L61-L80), you'll see it accepts `D: Digest`, which is to say: it accepts an arbitrary type `D` provided that `D` implements the `Digest` trait.  In other words: `Hmac::new` can accept any **single** type that implements `Digest`, not **all** of them.  That would require dynamic typing, which Rust doesn't have.  Also, your statement "**not** only the type which `Sha256` has" is misleading: `Sha256` doesn't have a type, it **is** a type.

Comment: **it accepts an arbitrary type D provided that D implements the Digest trait.** - does Sha256 implement it? Yes. does Sha384 implement it? Yes. does Sha512 implement it? Yes.

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp: Again, irrelevant.  Each `Sha*` is a different type.  Each `Hmac<Sha*>` is a different type.  It doesn't matter what traits they do or don't implement.  `Hmac` can only deal with **one** of those types at a time.  If this still doesn't make sense, I can only suggest you go and re-read the [Rust Book section on Traits](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/traits.html), particularly where "monomorphization" is explained.

Comment: Do you mean Rust has to know the  exact type of Digest statically, during the compile-time?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp: No, it has to know the type of `D`, which is simply a type that implements `Digest`.  SO is now warning against long comment discussions; if you still don't understand, I'd recommend asking on the [#rust IRC channel](https://chat.mibbit.com/?server=irc.mozilla.org&channel=%23rust).